# How to open a file in TYPO3 extbase extension controller?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

I need to read an file inside of the extension controller, here as example my extension key is `myext_key` and the file I want to open is a JSON file `data.json` in the `Resources/Private/JSON` directory. My research gave me, that the best way to open a file wouldn't be with `file_get_contents($path)`, instead with `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getURL($path)`.

So I tried it with the following code, but that didn't work:

```
$content = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getURL('EXT:myext_key/Resources/Private/JSON/data.json');
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if anything is wrong with `file_get_contents()`, other than memory implications, because `file_get_contents()` essentially assigns a variable with the whole file content. As long as you are dealing with a small .json file is small you should be in the safe.

The method to get the absolute file name of a file inside an extension directory is `getFileAbsFileName()`

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:myext_key/Resources/Private/JSON/data.json')
);
```